# "Walk around in Las Vegas" or "walk around Las Vegas"?

Tags: prepositions

Is it wrong to add "in" after "around" in the given phrase?

> walk around Las Vegas

Comment: If you include the preposition ***in***, this would rule out the possibility of your text being understood as a reference to walking ***around the perimeter*** of Vegas. But that's a perverse interpretation anyway, so it's not important. So it's basically just a stylistic choice.

Comment: There's already an idiom -- "walk around zzz", so don't complicate it by adding unnecessary words.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is, no, it is not wrong to put **in**  after **around**.

But by putting an **in** into the sentence, it means you walk around in the city, Las Vegas and the sentence can not be understood otherwise. However if you left out the **in**, it could also be understood as if you are walking around the perimeter/area of Las Vegas. (not necessarily inside the city)

Comment: "walk around Las Vegas" doesn't necessarily mean around the perimeter, but it does imply that you are covering most of Las Vegas: it's common to "walk around a zoo" or "walk around a museum", which means you see most or all of the sights there. In contrast "walk around in Las Vegas" could just mean you go out for a wander near your hotel.

Comment: @StuartF Exactly my point 

Answer (score 0):

It wouldn't be wrong to add 'in'. However, I think it would insinuate a meaning that is different from the meaning of the sentence without 'in'. As the previous person stated, 'walk around Las Vegas' could imply that the person walked around the perimeter of Las Vegas, whereas 'walk around in Las Vegas' would mean inside the city. But I'd add that another difference could be that 'walk around' would mean walking around not a specific part of Las Vegas, but rather Las Vegas in general, while 'walk around in' implies walking around a more localized, small area within Las Vegas.

Comment: Can you edit this to provide more information as at the moment it does not seem to add much to the existing answer?